# Application using TRESTClient hungs on a new machine

Tags: delphi

I made a small test application using `TRESTClient` and `TRESTRequest`. On the development machine (where Delphi is installed) everything works fine. If I move the exe on another machine, the application hungs after I press the button. What dll files do I have to deploy with this simple application? 
Here is the code:

```
procedure TForm44.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LClient: TRESTClient;
  LRequest: TRESTRequest;
begin
  LClient := TRESTClient.Create('https://secure.authorize.net/');
  LClient.FallbackCharsetEncoding := '';
  LRequest := TRESTRequest.Create(nil);
  try
    LRequest.Client := LClient;
    LRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
    LRequest.Resource := 'gateway/transact.dll';
    // merchant info
    LRequest.AddParameter('x_login', 'test', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
    LRequest.AddParameter('x_tran_key', 'test1', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
    LRequest.AddParameter('x_version', '3.1', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
    LRequest.AddParameter('x_test_request', 'TRUE', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
    LRequest.AddParameter('x_method', 'CC', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
    LRequest.AddParameter('x_type', 'AUTH_CAPTURE', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
    LRequest.AddParameter('x_amount', '10', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
    LRequest.AddParameter('x_delim_data', 'TRUE', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
    LRequest.AddParameter('x_relay_response', 'FALSE', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
    LRequest.AddParameter('x_description', 'Delphi_Transaction', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);

    LRequest.Execute;
    memo1.Lines.Text := LRequest.Response.Content;

  finally
    LClient.Free;
    LRequest.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What makes you think there are any DLLs involved? If your app static links to missing DLLs, it won't even start at all. If your app loads DLLs dynamically, I would expect runtime crashes/errors to happen, not hangs. Something else is likely going on.

Comment: @RemyLebeau There are no DLLs loaded dynamically in code. The test application just has a memo, a button and the code posted here. What could cause the application to stop responding when I press the button though? Like I said, on the development machine the application works 100% fine.

Comment: "*What could cause the application to stop responding when I press the button though?*" - Well, you are performing a blocking operation in the main UI thread, after all. That will make the UI unresponsive until the operation is finished. You are just going to have to debug your code to find out why the operation hangs.  On the other hand, you shouldn't be performing a blocking operation in the main UI thread to begin with.  Move the operation to a separate worker thread that notifies the main UI thread when finished.

Comment: @RemyLebeau this is just a test application, just to see what's happening. The UI is not stuck just for a second until the blocking operation is done. As soon as the button is pressed the application hangs until I kill it. On the development machine I get the response back right away. My final code is part of a service and runs in its own thread, but same thing happens there.

Comment: "*As soon as the button is pressed the application hangs until I kill it*" - again, the ONLY way that can happen is if the REST operation hangs. So get it out of the UI thread to begin with. "*My final code is part of a service and runs in its own thread, but same thing happens there*" - all the more reason to DEBUG YOUR CODE

Comment: @RemyLebeau The error is "ServerCertificateInvalid" and THTTPClient (used by TRESTClient) gets stuck in a loop trying to DoValidateServerCertificate in THTTPClient.ExecuteHTTPInternal(...). It seems that this problem appears on multiple windows server machines I tested. I also tried updating the root certs from Microsoft but that didn't do anything either. I changed my code to use TIdHttp and now it works fine.